# Check if Mac process is running using Bash by process name

Tags: macos, bash, unix, process

How do you check if a process on Mac OS X is running using the process's name in a Bash script?

I am trying to write a Bash script that will restart a process if it has stopped but do nothing if it is still running.

Comment: I'm adding "unix" to the list of tags because there's really nothing mac specific about this question... (Leaving "mac" so mac specific people will find it as well...)

Comment: BTW, if you are creating a daemon-like process on OS X, you should take a look at `launchd`, Apple's replacement for `cron`, `init`, `inetd` et al.  It has many options to start and restart processes in various contexts and times.  See `man launchd`, `man launchd.plist`, and google for various docs and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I am actually using Lingon as a user-friendly interface to `launchd`.

Comment: Brian, you are half-wrong. Mac OS X is based on BSD and have slightly different semantics in many commands involved in getting this right. Not that I think the Linux tag is inappropriate, though.

Comment: I had to solve this problem for Mac OS X, OpenBSD, various Linux'es, AIX, Solaris and Cygwin in one and the same system (a build system). It ended up being easier using two-phase locking with temporary files and process monitoring, rather than just process monitoring (eg. 'ps' alone). That isn't really an answer to your question though, but consider it general advice. One of the larger headaches was that (especially in Mac OS X) the ps arguments changed with various versions of the OS.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Parsing this:

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -c [-i] $ProcessName
```

...is probably your best bet.

`ps aux` lists all the currently running processes including the Bash script itself which is parsed out by `grep -v grep` with advice from Jacob (in comments) and `grep -c [-i] $ProcessName` returns the optionally case-insensitive integer number of processes with integer return suggested by Sebastian.

Here's a short script that does what you're after:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROCESS=myapp
number=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -ci $PROCESS)

if [ $number -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo Running;
fi
```

**EDIT:** I initially included a `-i` flag to `grep` to make it case insensitive; I did this because the example program I tried was `python`, which on Mac OS X runs as `Python` -- if you know your application's case exactly, the `-i` is not necessary.

The advantage of this approach is that it scales with you -- in the future, if you need to make sure, say, *five* instances of your application are running, you're already counting.  The only caveat is if another application has your program's name in its command line, it might come up -- regular expressions to `grep` will resolve that issue, if you're crafty (and run into this).

Research the Darwin man pages for [`ps`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html), [`grep`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html), and [`wc`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/wc.1.html).

Comment: Thanks. This worked with one exception: it has to be `-gt 1` rather than `0`, because the `grep` command from the Bash script itself gets counted as one of the lines in the `ps aux`, at least in my preliminary tests.

Comment: I like to add a `grep -v grep` to the pipeline before the `wc`.  That way, the grep command gets excluded from the number of matches found.

Comment: Does it work with really long filenames and paths? Especially if they are similar in the beginning?, eg. my-long-filename-that-is-really-stupid-of-file-1, my-long-filename-that-is-really-stupid-of-file-2... I bet it doesn't, at least not on both Linux and Mac OS X, using the same arguments to ps...

Comment: Jed & Chris, you can use another negative `grep` for 'grep' to maintain `-gt 0` functionality. For example: `ps aux | grep -i $ProcessName | grep -v grep | wc -l`.

Comment: You don't have to chain so many commands. grep provides everything you need: `num=$(ps ax | grep -c -i "[Tt]ransmission")`

Comment: I've create a gist if anybody need it. 

    `$ ./process_running.sh compass`


https://gist.github.com/sobi3ch/6494891

Comment: Are there any advantages to using this method over `pgrep` (see @Nick Zalutskiy's answer)?

Answer (score 38):

A shorter solution:

```
if pgrep $PROCESS_NAME; then
    echo 'Running';
fi
```

Explanation:

`pgrep` exits with 0 if there is a process matching `$PROCESS_NAME` running, otherwise it exist with 1.
`if` checks the exit code of `pgrep`, and, as far as exit codes go, 0 is success.

Comment: You might want to use `-x` though, because by default it matches on substrings. `-x` changes this behaviour such that it requires an exact match of the process name.

Comment: @Hypermattt It's not the accepted answer because he wrote it 4 years after I asked the question. Cool solution, though. Definitely has my up vote.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately if you're running something in a wrapper (e.g. python). Jed Smith's solution might work there better

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to use (abuse?) the `-d` option of the `killall` command.  The `-d` options won't actually kill the process, but instead print what will be done.  It will also exit with status `0` if it finds a matching process, or `1` if it does not.  Putting this together:

```
#!/bin/bash
`/usr/bin/killall -d "$1" &> /dev/null`
let "RUNNING = ! $?"     # this simply does a boolean 'not' on the return code
echo $RUNNING
```

To give credit where its due, I originally pulled this technique from a script in the iTunes installer.

Comment: EWW. I'm not going to -1 because I think that should only be used for incorrect or inappropriate answers, but wow. Why do that when you can use ps and grep? especially since I'm pretty sure that using ps and grep is exactly what killall does...

Comment: Actually killall is a little smarter than 'ps | grep'.  If you just grep the output of ps, you can get false positives.  Contrived, but say your process is named 'Library'.  'ps waux | grep Library' will match a lot of stuff on a Mac.  The killall method, while a bit wacky I admit, will only match an actual process named 'Library'.

Comment: I'm sorry but what system are you using? I'm not seeing -d option in killall command. http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall

Comment: @sobi3ch: The discussion is about the absence of `pidof` on Mac OS X, not Linux.  The `-d` option is documented by `man killall` on Mac OS X.  There is not necessarily much commonality between programs of the same name on different O/S unless there's been some standardization — de facto or de jure.

Answer (score 5):

This simple command will do the trick.  The brackets around the process name prevent the grep command from showing in the process list.  Note there is no space after the comma.  There may be some portability issues as **ps** on some unix systems may require a dash before the options:

```
ps axo pid,command | grep "[S]kype"
```

The advantage is that you can use the results in an if statement like this:'

```
if [[ ! $(ps axo pid,command | grep "[i]Tunes.app") ]]; then
    open -a iTunes
fi
```

Or if you prefer this style:

```
[[ ! $(ps axo pid,command | grep "[S]kype") ]] && open -a Skype  || echo "Skype is up"
```

Another advantage is that you can get the pid by adding a pipe to awk '{print $1}'.

```
echo "iTunes pid: $(ps axo pid,command | grep "[i]Tunes.app" | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use either killall or kill, depending on if you are trying to find the task by PID or by name.

By Name:

```
if ! killall -s -0 $PROCESS_NAME >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  # Restart failed app, or do whatever you need to prepare for starting the app.
else
  at -f $0 +30seconds # If you don't have this on cron, you can use /usr/bin/at
fi
```

By PID:

```
if ! kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null; then
  # Restart app, do the needful.
else
  at -f $0 +30seconds
fi
```

If you look at the **OSX Manual** you will see a different set of process management commands; since it's not the linux kernel, it makes sense that they would manage processes differently.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/killall.1.html

A sample output from my terminal (striking out the user and hostname, of course):

```
user@localhost:~$ kill -0 782 # This was my old, stale SSH Agent.
bash: kill: (782) - No such process
user@localhost:~$ echo $?
1

user@localhost:~$ kill -0 813 # This is my new SSH agent, I only just created.
user@localhost:~$ echo $?
0
```

The return code from a kill -0 will always result in a safe way to check if the process is running, because -0 sends no signal that will ever be handled by an application. It won't kill the application, and "kill" is only called "kill" because it's usually used to stop an application.

When you look at the interfaces it uses in the source, you'll see that it's actually interacting with the process table directly (and not grepping a potentially loaded output from ps), and just sending a signal to an application. Some signals indicate the application should shutdown or stop, while other signals tell it to restart services, or re-read configuration, or re-open file descriptors to log files that have been recently rotated. There are a plethora of things that "kill" and "killall" can do that doesn't terminate the application, and it's used regularly to simply send a signal to the application.

Answer (score 2):

I lack the reputation to comment on the killall answer above, but there's `killall -s` for doing it without sending any signals:

```
killall -s "$PROCESSNAME" &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$PROCESSNAME is running"
    # if you also need the PID:
    PID=`killall -s "$PROCESSNAME" | awk '{print $3}'`
    echo "it's PID is $PID"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It has for sure!

pgrep, pkill and pfind for OpenBSD and Darwin (Mac OS X)

http://proctools.sourceforge.net

(also available via MacPorts: port info proctools )

pidof by nightproductions.net

Comment: Great stuff, but not in standard. Sometimes it is better to solve this problem only using the standard stuff, sometimes not!

Answer (score 1):

I've extended a pidof script found on the net to use regular expressions (usually substrings) and be case insensitive

```
#!/bin/sh
ps axc  |awk "BEGIN{ n=tolower(\"$1\")}\
    tolower(\$5) ~n {print  \$1}";
```

just create a script named "pidof" with this content, and put it in you path, i.e. in one of the dirs in

```
echo $PATH
```

and make it executable (maybe using sudo)

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/pidof
```

and use it like this, of course

```
kill -9 `pidof pyth`
```

Answer (score 0):

does Mac have pidof? ...

```
if pidof $processname >/dev/null ; then echo $processname is running ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late for the OP but this may help others who find this thread.

The following modification of the amrox theme above works well for restarting applications on my OS X:

```
killall -d TextEdit &> /dev/null && killall TextEdit &> /dev/null; open -a TextEdit
```

I use the following AppleScript to update and restart daemons:

```
tell application "System Events" to set pwd to POSIX path of container of (path to me)
do shell script "launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/time-test.plist; cp -f " & quoted form of pwd & "/time-test.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons; launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/time-test.plist" with administrator privileges
```

It assumes the original or updated plist file is in the same directory as the AppleScript.